# The IO action ‘main’ is not exported by module ‘Main’

Tags: haskell

I have two haskell files named SimpleJSON.hs and another is Main.hs

```
--File: SimpleJSON.hs
module SimpleJSON
(
    JValue (..)
    ,getString
    ,getInt
    ,getDouble
    ,getBool
    ,getObject
    ,getArray
    ,isNull
) where

data JValue = JString String
        | JNumber Double
        | JBool Bool
        | JNull
        | JObject [(String, JValue)]
        | JArray [JValue]
          deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
```

And

```
--File: Main.hs
module Main () where
import SimpleJSON
main = print (JObject [("foo", JNumber 1), ("bar", JBool False)])
```

So while compiling 
I am doing

```
ghc -c SimpleJSON.hs
```

and

```
ghc simple Main.hs SimpleJSON.o
```

Then I am getting error as

```
Main.hs:1:1: error:
The IO action ‘main’ is not exported by module ‘Main’
  |
1 | module Main () where
  | ^
```

How to resolve this compilation error?

Comment: Real-world newby here. I was doing the same example from "Real World Haskell" and ran into the same problem. Just wanted to name-drop the book here. I bought this book in 2023 and I am disappointed that it was not revised to keep with the times, but it still seemed like the best choice.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Should be

```
module Main where
```

or

```
module Main (main) where
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked just fine. Can you elaborate more on this?as I am just a newbie for this.

Comment: well, by using the `()` you can limit what functions are exported from the module. see e.g. http://learnyouahaskell.com/modules#making-our-own-modules

Comment: Summary: `module Name` exports everything, `module Name ()` exports only typeclass instances, and `module Name (…)` exports only the entities named in `…`. I tend to use `module Main (main)` because then I get warnings about any unused definitions in the module with `-Wall` (or `-fwarn-unused-binds` specifically).

Answer (score 7):

This answer for specifically for reader of [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org). It seems that the book uses an older version of Haskell where `main` need not be explicitly mentioned in the list of exports. In the latest version, this is no longer the case.

There are two aspects that need to be mentioned:

- you need to write `module Main (main) where` so that `main` is exported
- you do not need to make an object file of `SimpleJSON.hs` and mention it while compiling `Main.hs` i.e simply running `ghc -o simple Main.hs` will suffice

As a general note, a couple of reviews on the [Amazon page for the book](https://www.amazon.in/Real-World-Haskell-Bryan-%E2%80%B2sullivan/dp/0596514980/ref=sr_1_2?keywords=real+world+haskell&qid=1570297306&sr=8-2) mention that some aspects covered in the book are out of date. So, if you are following this book, make it a point to use another source to catch up on the differences.